# How to check if `fgets` was interrupted via `SIGINT` on Windows?

Tags: windows, console

I have a `fgets` loop that currently checks if it got a line. If it did, continue. If not, finish the loop. However, upon pressing `ctrl-c` a signal is sent and `fgets` exits without an error or a line and thus `ferror` returns nothing and no string was returned.

Is there any way I can check to see if it was merely interrupted?

Comment: If you have to stick with `fgets`, then one option is to register a control handler that sets an event object for Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Break. Your code will have to wait on the event if `fgets` returns with an empty result. The control handler is called in a new thread that's created by csrss.exe in response to a request from conhost.exe, so you have to wait for 100ms or so to give it adequate time. But wait much longer and the interface will feel lagged.

Comment: What's the alternative without `fgets`?

Comment: If you can rewrite your code to use the Windows API directly, call `ReadConsoleW` (or `ReadConsoleA` if you insist on using legacy codepages instead of Unicode). A call that's interrupted by Ctrl+C still 'succeeds', but the last error will be set to `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED`. (This no longer works with `ReadFile` in Windows 8+ due to a bug that has yet to be fixed in 6 years.)

Comment: hmm. So the code is generic for different file handles and not necessarily always from the console. So that means that `ReadFile` won't work, correct? And thus I have to do the method from your first response?

Comment: If you have a console input handle, as detected by `GetConsoleMode`, then call `ReadConsole`. Otherwise call `ReadFile`.